# How to update PowerBI Datasource credentials for an Azure AD application (service principal)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have an Azure AD Service Principal which is the admin of a Azure SQL Database. There is a PowerBI dashboard with a DataSource that connects to the Database. After publishing the dashboard programmatically (CI/CD), I need to update the parameters and the Datasource credentials.

Considering the examples from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/update-datasource#examples),  **what `credentialDetails` definition is required to authenticate to Azure SQL Server using a Service Principal client id and credential?**

The only way I managed to have access with the SP was using `OAuth2` with an `accessToken` for the database scope. However, the token expires in 1 hour which would force a redeployment of the  dashboard continuously.

```
{
  "credentialDetails": {
    "credentialType": "OAuth2",
    "credentials": "{\"credentialData\":[{\"name\":\"accessToken\", \"value\":\"eyJ0....fwtQ\"}]}",
    "encryptedConnection": "Encrypted",
    "encryptionAlgorithm": "None",
    "privacyLevel": "None"
  }
}
```

Using Azure AD Service Principal authentication is required for compliance policies within the company.

---

Example of the error message when using `Basic` credential type is used:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_DataSourceAccessError",
      "pbi.error":{
         "code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_DataSourceAccessError",
         "parameters":{
            
         },
         "details":[
            {
               "code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"-2146232060"
               }
            },
            {
               "code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"Login failed for user 'aad_app_name'. Reason: Azure Active Directory only authentication is enabled. Please contact your system administrator."
               }
            },
            {
               "code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"-2146232060"
               }
            },
            {
               "code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingNativeErrorCode",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"18456"
               }
            }
         ],
         "exceptionCulprit":1
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Found similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67826138/377118

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
 Login failed for user 'username'. Reason: Azure Active Directory only authentication is enabled.
      Please contact your system administrator.
```

occurs `Azure AD-only authentication` is enabled while trying to test with (SSMS) to actually connect to SQL Database or SQL Managed Instance as ***`in  this case SQL authentication is disabled at the server or managed instance level and prevents any authentication based on any SQL authentication credentials`***. So try using SQL authentication for the connection.

To allow both SQL  and Azure AD authentication for Azure SQL to connect,
We may need to disable the Azure AD-only authentication.

To disable using Azure cli.

- Sign into Azure account having the [SQL Security Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#sql-security-manager) role.

  `az login`
- diasble command by  replacing  with SQL server name, and  with your
  Azure Resource that holds the SQL server

  `az sql server ad-only-auth disable --resource-group <myresource> --name <myserver>`

After disabling Azure AD-only authentication, try updating the credentials .

You can also disable by using azure portal by  unchecking the Support only Azure Active Directory authentication for this server .
[image]

**Reference** :
[Enable Azure Active Directory only authentication - Azure SQL Database & Azure SQL Managed Instance | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-only-authentication-tutorial?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#test-sql-authentication-with-connection-failure)

Also please check the code snippet below  from [update Azure SQL datasource credentials of PowerBI dataset programmatically? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309793/how-to-update-azure-sql-datasource-credentials-of-powerbi-dataset-programmatical) using with [Microsoft powerbi commandlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps) if required.

```
$patchBody = @{
    "credentialDetails" = @{
      "credentials" = "{""credentialData"":[ $userNameJson, $passwordJson ]}"
      "credentialType" = "Basic"
      "encryptedConnection" =  "NotEncrypted"
      "encryptionAlgorithm" = "None"
      "privacyLevel" = "Organizational"
    }
  }

  # Convert body contents to JSON
  $patchBodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $patchBody -Depth 6 -Compress

  #PATCH operation to update datasource credentials
  Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Patch -Url $datasourePatchUrl -Body $patchBodyJson
```

Comment: Thanks Kavya for the detailed explanation. The answer suggests to do a workaround by enabling SQL Authentication and disabling Azure AD-only authentication. Does that mean, it is not possible to do what I am asking?

Comment: If  Azure AD-only authentication feature is disabled, it means you will be allowing both SQL authentication and Azure AD authentication for Azure SQL. And yes ,AFAIK its not possible only with azure ad enabled if it requies to connect to Azure SQL Server through (server)ssms .But you may force to use servers  by AzureADONLY using  [azure policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-only-authentication?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-cli#feature-description) but also please check the limitation below.